# Date in BigQuery

Tags: date, timestamp, google-bigquery

I have a date vector in integer form of

20140117

20130325

20130530

etc. How can I transfer it to a datevector recognized by BigQuery? I tried to use Timestamp but it does not recognise the different parts of the vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import it as a String, then you can run an ETL inside BigQuery easily:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP('20140117')

2014-01-17 00:00:00 UTC
```

Comment: In this case it would be simply timestamp(string(Date))